# Como ordenar Registros de manera Descendente - C++

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos, dev-c++, ordenamiento, registro

realicé este programa para un proyecto de la Universidad, el enunciado es el siguiente:

Se solicita crear un programa que pueda almacenar datos de hasta 10 empleados (Registros). Para cada registro, debe guardar los siguientes datos: Nombre del empleado (Nombre y Apellido), Edad y Salario

El programa mostrará un menú que permita al usuario las siguientes operaciones:

- Añadir datos de un nuevo registro (validar si hay espacio para un nuevo registro)
- Mostrar los nombres de todos los empleados almacenados
- Mostrar los registros de aquellos empleados que ganan más de 1000 balboas y calcular el promedio de salarios de todos los empleados.
- Ver todos los datos de un cierto registro (a partir de su nombre) y solicitar si va a realizar alguna modificación de los datos del registro.
- Mostrar en orden descendente por salario, la lista de empleados
- Salir de la aplicación

Hice el código que presento a continuación pero tengo problemas con el punto que dice:

- Mostrar en orden descendente por salario, la lista de empleados.
  He intentado de diferente maneras pero no logro completarlo.

El problema inicia en el case 5, aproximadamente la linea 221.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "cstring"
#include "cstdlib"
#include "string"
//system("pause") system("cls");

using namespace std;


//DECLARACION DE ESTRUCTURAS
struct nombre {
    char nombre[30];
    char ape[30];
};

struct persona {

    struct nombre persona;
    int edad;
    float sal;

};

//Declaracion de Variables
float sal_myr,sal_mnr,sal_mil;
int i,j,seleccion,seleccion2,seleccion3,salida=1,salida2=1,salida3=1;
struct persona newempleado;
struct persona empleado[10];
struct persona emptemp;
int numemp=0;
float promsal, totsal, temp;
char nomcheck[30], apecheck[30];
int res;

//Main del Programa
int main(){
    
    menu:system("cls");
    cout << "Proyecto 1 - Registros" << endl;
    while (salida==1){
    cout << "Ingrese una de las siguientes opciones: " << endl;
    cout << "Crear Nuevo Registro [1]" << endl;
    cout << "Ver Registros [2]" << endl;
    cout << "Salir [3]" << endl;
    cin >> seleccion;
    switch (seleccion) {
        default:
            system("cls");
            cout << "Por favor, Ingrese una opcion valida: " << endl;
            system("pause");
            goto menu;
            case 1 :
            system("cls");
            //Nuevo Registro de Empleado
            cout << "Creacion del Registro " << endl;
            if (numemp>10){
                cout << "No quedan mas espacios de registro" << endl;
            }
            else {    
                cout << "\nDatos de Empleado " << numemp+1 << endl;
    
                cout << "Nombre: " << endl;
                cin >> empleado[numemp].persona.nombre;
                cout << "Apellido: " << endl;
                cin >> empleado[numemp].persona.ape;
                cout << "Edad: " << endl;
                cin >> empleado[numemp].edad;
                cout << "Salario: " << endl;
                cin >> empleado[numemp].sal;
                numemp++;
}
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
            break;
            
            case 2 :
        VRegistro:system("cls");                
                while (salida2==1){
    cout << "\nIngrese una de las siguientes opciones: " << endl;
    cout << "Ver todos los nombres de los empleados [1]" << endl;
    cout << "Ver los registros de los empleados que ganan mas de 1000 balboas [2]" << endl;
    cout << "Promedio de los salarios de los empleados [3]" << endl;
    cout << "Ver o Editar un registro especifico [4]" << endl;
    cout << "Ver registros (orden descendente por salario) [5]" << endl;
    cout << "Salir [6]" << endl;
    cin >> seleccion2;
    switch (seleccion2) {
        default:
            system("cls");
            cout << "Por favor, Ingrese una opcion valida: " << endl;
            system("pause");
            goto VRegistro;
            case 1 :
                system("cls");
                
                //Nombre de todos los empleados
                cout << "Nombres de los empleados" << endl;
                for (int i=0; i <numemp; i++) {
                cout <<"Nombre: "<<empleado[i].persona.nombre << " " << empleado[i].persona.ape << endl;
                }
                //FIN
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;
            
            case 2 :
                system("cls");
                
                //Registros de Empleados que ganan mas de 1000
                for (int i=0; i <=numemp; i++) {

             if (empleado[i].sal > 1000) {
                    cout <<"Nombre: "<< empleado[i].persona.nombre << " " << empleado[i].persona.ape << endl;
                    cout <<"Edad: "<< empleado[i].edad << endl;
                 cout <<"Salario: "<< empleado[i].sal << endl;
             }
            }
                //FIN
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;

            case 3 :
                system("cls");
                //Promedio de todos salarios
            totsal=0;
            for (int i=0; i <=numemp; i++) {

            totsal = totsal + empleado[i].sal;
            }
            promsal = (float)totsal / numemp;
            cout<<"El Promedio de todos los salarios es: "<<promsal<<endl;
            //FIN
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;

            case 4 :
                system("cls");
                
                        VEspecifico:system("cls");
                        cout << " " << endl;
                        while (salida3==1){
                        cout << "Ingrese una de las siguientes opciones: " << endl;
                        cout << "Ver un registro especifico [1]" << endl;
                        cout << "Editar un registro especifico [2]" << endl;
                        cout << "Salir [3]" << endl;
                        cin >> seleccion3;
                        switch (seleccion3) {
                            default:
                            system("cls");
                            cout << "Por favor, Ingrese una opcion valida: " << endl;
                            system("pause");
                            goto VEspecifico;
            
                            case 1 :
                                system("cls");
                
                                //Chequear Registro
                                cout << "Ingrese Nombre: " << endl;
                                cin >> nomcheck;
                                cout << "Ingrese Apellido: " << endl;
                                cin >> apecheck;
                                for (int i=0; i <=numemp; i++) {
                             if(strcmp(nomcheck, empleado[i].persona.nombre) == 0 && strcmp(apecheck, empleado[i].persona.ape) == 0){
                                cout << "Datos del Empleado " <<nomcheck<<" "<<apecheck << endl;
                                cout << "Edad: " << empleado[i].edad << endl;
                                cout << "Salario: " << empleado[i].sal << endl;
    }
}
                                system("pause");
                                system("cls");
                                break;
            
                            case 2 :
                                system("cls");
                                //Cambiar datos de un registro
                                cout << "Ingrese nombre y apellido del registro a sobreescribir: " << endl;
                                cout << "Nombre: " << endl;
                                cin >> nomcheck;
                                cout << "Apellido: " << endl;
                                cin >> apecheck;

                                for (int i=0; i<numemp; i++) {
                                 if((strcmp(nomcheck,empleado[i].persona.nombre)==0) && strcmp(apecheck, empleado[i].persona.ape)==0){

                                    cout << "\nDatos de Empleado " <<nomcheck<<" "<<apecheck<< endl;
                                    cout << "Nombre: " << endl;
                                    cin >> empleado[i].persona.nombre;
                                    cout << "Apellido: " << endl;
                                    cin >> empleado[i].persona.ape;
                                    cout << "Edad: " << endl;
                                    cin >> empleado[i].edad;
                                    cout << "Salario: " << endl;
                                    cin >> empleado[i].sal;
}
}
//FIN
                                system("pause");
                                system("cls");
                                break;

                            case 3 :
                                system("cls");
                                salida3++;
                                break;
                        }
            }
                    
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
                break;
                
                
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;  
                
            case 5 :
                system("cls");
                //Orden Descendente
    


                
                //FIN
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                break;  
                
            case 6 :
                system("cls");
                salida2++;
                break;
                }
                
                    
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
                break;

            
                //Salida
                
                case 3 :
                    system("cls");
                    cout << "Que tenga un buen dia. ";
                    salida++;
                    break;
                }
            }
    }
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Ordena los datos de forma descendente por salario, y luego los muestras. En serio hacen falta 250 lineas de codigo para entender tu problema? Te recomiendo que veas como traer un [ejemplo minimo completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Asi se nos hara mas facil ayudarte en un futuro.

Comment: El `case 5` está vacío ¿Cuál es exactamente el problema que encuentras?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster el problema es que no encuentro una manera de ordenar en orden descendente los registros, esperaba alguna recomendación.

Comment: @CarlosDaniel Aprende algún algoritmo para ordenar datos y úsalo. O usa `std::sort`. Posdata: [Este eres tu?](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp_questions/comments/nbc8vd/issues_when_testing_the_code/) Si no lo eres te conviene igual leer las recomendaciones que estan haciendo, le vendrian de maravilla a tu codigo.

Comment: @CarlosDaniel es muy difícil recomendarte algo útil si no tenemos una base sobre la que elaborar la recomendación; con lo que has aportado el único consejo que te puedo dar es: "*Para ordenar de manera descendente, ordenas de manera descendente*".

Answer (score -1):

Si, yo también tuve problemas para hallar la forma de ordenar un array de estructuras, por lo general yo recurro a la función qsort de la librería <stdlib.h> precisamente porque ya viene de "fabrica" y no tienes que idear desde cero un algoritmo de ordenación, qsort se utiliza pasándole cuatro argumentos, estos son, el array, la cantidad de elementos que contiene el array, el tamaño que ocupa un elemento (en bytes) y por ultimo, una función, que es la que realiza la comparación de los miembros de la estructura que te interesa ordenar, es gracias a esta funcion que qsort sabe exactamente que valores debe comparar para poder llevar a cabo la ordenación, en el código que muestro dejo un ejemplo de cómo llamar la función de ordenamiento qsort y cómo es el prototipo de la función de comparación que debe tener para que realice el trabajo deseado. Espero te sirva para que tengas una idea mas clara de como implementar qsort en tu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

const int MAX = 5;

struct Empleado{
    char nombre[16];
    char apellido[20];
    int edad;
};

void entrada(const char *mensaje, char cadena[]){
    std::cout<<mensaje;
    std::cin>>cadena;
    fflush(stdin);
}

void entrada(const char *mensaje, int &entero){
    std::cout<<mensaje;
    std::cin>>entero;
    fflush(stdin);
}

void llenarColeccion(Empleado coleccion[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        entrada("Nombre  : ",coleccion[i].nombre);
        entrada("Apellido: ",coleccion[i].apellido);
        entrada("Edad    : ",coleccion[i].edad);
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

void mostrar(Empleado coleccion[]){
    int contador = 0;

    printf("%-9s%-13s%-13s%s\n","Numero","Nombre","Apellido","Edad");
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        printf("%-9d%-13s%-13s%d\n",++contador,coleccion[i].nombre,coleccion[i].apellido,coleccion[i].edad);
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl<<std::endl;
    system("pause");
}

int compararNombre(const void *p, const void *q){
    Empleado a = *(Empleado*)p;
    Empleado b = *(Empleado*)q;

    if(strcmp(a.nombre,b.nombre) > 0) return 1;
    if(strcmp(a.nombre,b.nombre) == 0) return 0;

    return -1;
}

int compararApellido(const void *p, const void *q){
    Empleado a = *(Empleado*)p;
    Empleado b = *(Empleado*)q;

    if(strcmp(a.apellido,b.apellido) > 0) return 1;
    if(strcmp(a.apellido,b.apellido) == 0) return 0;

    return -1;
}

int compararEdad(const void *p, const void *q){
    Empleado a = *(Empleado*)p;
    Empleado b = *(Empleado*)q;

    if(a.edad > b.edad) return 1;
    if(a.edad == b.edad) return 0;

    return -1;
}

int main(void){
    //array de estructuras con longitud definido por la constante MAX
    Empleado coleccion[MAX];

    std::cout<<"\tIngresando datos\n\n";
    llenarColeccion(coleccion);

    std::cout<<"\tMostrando datos\n\n";
    mostrar(coleccion);

    //llamada a la funcion qsort, criterio de ordenamiento: nombre
    qsort(coleccion,MAX,sizeof(Empleado),compararNombre);
    std::cout<<"\tMostrando datos ordenado por nombre\n\n";
    mostrar(coleccion);

    //llamada a la funcion qsort, criterio de ordenamiento: apellido
    qsort(coleccion,MAX,sizeof(Empleado),compararApellido);
    std::cout<<"\tMostrando datos ordenado por apellido\n\n";
    mostrar(coleccion);

    //llamada a la funcion qsort, criterio de ordenamiento: edad
    qsort(coleccion,MAX,sizeof(Empleado),compararEdad);
    std::cout<<"\tMostrando datos ordenado por edad\n\n";
    mostrar(coleccion);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Si estas usando c++ lo correcto seria que usaras `std::sort`, en lugar de `qsort` que es de C y es menos eficiente.